# Date format changes when saving admin config twice

Tags: magento-1.9

I have implemented a date selection field in my admin config using this Block as a frontend model:

```
<?php
class Jurgis_Twilio_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Date extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{
    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $date = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date();
        $format = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);

        $data = array(
            'name'      => $element->getName(),
            'html_id'   => $element->getId(),
            'image'     => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        );
        $date->setData($data);
        $date->setValue($element->getValue(), $format);
        $date->setFormat(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT));
        $date->setForm($element->getForm());

        return $date->getElementHtml();
    }
}
```

The functionality is working fine, but when I initially select a date, it displays it as: [image]

After I click "save config" it changes to: [image] 
 but the value of that field is still "07/11/2017" and only after I save the config the second time it changes to "7/11/2017".

I don't really care which format, but I need it to be constant and final, after the first save. Can I add something in the Block to fix this?